# How to extract the five numbers of geom_boxplot into a table?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, geom

I´m having some troubles trying to extract into a table the five number values of a `geom_boxplot`. I know it works easily with boxplot$stats, however, I cannot find the way to extract the same information from a boxplot made in `ggplot2`. Can anyone help me?

this is the code of the graph:

```
graf332 <- bd %>%
 filter(!(DIAGNOST %in% c("Otras Enf eosinofilicas del TGI", "Esofagitis Eosinofilica"
))) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = DIAGNOST, y = EDAD, fill = SEXO)) +
 geom_boxplot() +
 scale_fill_hue() +
 labs(x = "Diagnóstico", y = "Edad en meses", 
      title = "Distribución de la población por diagnóstico según edad en meses y discriminado por sexo",
      fill = "Sexo") +
 theme_minimal()
```

and this is the graph:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

For any layer in ggplot2, you can extract the underlying data with `layer_data()`. For boxplots, the whisker endpoints are `ymin` and `ymax`, the box endspoints are `lower` and `upper`, whereas the median is `middle`. This is documented in the 'computed variables' section of `?stat_boxplot`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, displ)) +
  geom_boxplot()

layer_data(g)
#>   ymin lower middle upper ymax outliers notchupper notchlower x flipped_aes
#> 1  5.7   5.7   6.20  6.20  6.2        7   6.553299   5.846701 1       FALSE
#> 2  1.8   2.0   2.20  2.80  3.3            2.384373   2.015627 2       FALSE
#> 3  1.8   2.4   2.80  3.50  4.2      5.3   3.071430   2.528570 3       FALSE
#> 4  3.0   3.3   3.30  3.80  4.0      2.4   3.538194   3.061806 4       FALSE
#> 5  2.7   3.9   4.70  4.70  5.9            4.920034   4.479966 5       FALSE
#> 6  1.6   1.9   2.20  3.25  4.6      5.4   2.560543   1.839457 6       FALSE
#> 7  2.5   4.0   4.65  5.30  6.5            4.910858   4.389142 7       FALSE
#>   PANEL group ymin_final ymax_final  xmin  xmax xid newx new_width weight
#> 1     1     1        5.7        7.0 0.625 1.375   1    1      0.75      1
#> 2     1     2        1.8        3.3 1.625 2.375   2    2      0.75      1
#> 3     1     3        1.8        5.3 2.625 3.375   3    3      0.75      1
#> 4     1     4        2.4        4.0 3.625 4.375   4    4      0.75      1
#> 5     1     5        2.7        5.9 4.625 5.375   5    5      0.75      1
#> 6     1     6        1.6        5.4 5.625 6.375   6    6      0.75      1
#> 7     1     7        2.5        6.5 6.625 7.375   7    7      0.75      1
#>   colour  fill size alpha shape linetype
#> 1 grey20 white  0.5    NA    19    solid
#> 2 grey20 white  0.5    NA    19    solid
#> 3 grey20 white  0.5    NA    19    solid
#> 4 grey20 white  0.5    NA    19    solid
#> 5 grey20 white  0.5    NA    19    solid
#> 6 grey20 white  0.5    NA    19    solid
#> 7 grey20 white  0.5    NA    19    solid
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>